# Calculus remark I forgot.

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have a set $X$. Let $a = \inf X$. then for all $n$,   $a + \frac{1}{n} \in X$.

maybe this is wrong anyway I am trying to show it. So, we know $a \leq x $ for all $x \in X$. By archimidean, can find $n$ such that $a + \frac{1}{n} \leq x$. Im stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance

Suppose $X \neq \varnothing$ and $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think you need more info on $X$, for instance, without knowing anything else $X$ could be a finite set with no $a + \frac{1}{n}$ in it.

Comment: You're going to need to put some more restrictions on $X$. For instance, this clearly doesn't hold for the empty set. Or the set of all integers. Or the set of negative real numbers. Or $[0,1] \backslash \{x:x=1/n,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Etc. But there's *something* there if you refine it a little bit.

Comment: Ok I did update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a nonempty set of real numbers with a lower bound, then $a=\inf X$ satisfies:

1. For all $x\in X$, $a\leq x$.
2. For each positive integer $n$, there exists $x\in X$ such that $x<a+\frac{1}{n}$.

However, you cannot conclude that $a+\frac{1}{n}$ is in $X$, only that it is not a lower bound for $X$, which follows from the definition of the infimum as the *greatest* lower bound of $X$.  For example, $X$ might only contain one element.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly false. Think of the set:
$$X = {1/3^n}$$
It's infimum is $0$, but $0+1/2 \notin X$.